# python get and re-use session-cookie help please?

Tags: python, urllib2, session-cookies

So I'm trying to scrape data from 12bet.co.uk.  I have the following python code aimed at the info I want:

```
import urllib2
sid = 'lgvvtb45xlqtwe45wjp3wy45'  # value copied from a Firefox session
url = 'http://eu.12bet.co.uk/EuroSite/Match_data.aspx?Scope=Sport&Id=1&Sport=1&Market=d&RT=W&Game=0&OddsType=1'
http_req_data = None
http_req_header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT' : '1',
    'Referer' : 'http://eu.12bet.co.uk/EuroSite/Euro_index.aspx',
    'Cookie' : 'MuSou_eu=20110303; iom_territory=UK; LangKey=en; OddsType_12BETUUS01015=1; ASP.NET_SessionId='+sid+'',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive'}
web_req = urllib2.Request(url, http_req_data, http_req_header)  # create request object
web_resp = urllib2.urlopen(web_req)  # open the request object and return a handle
print web_resp.info()
```

This works fine (Content-Length is large = lots of nice content returned) when I copy/paste a value for sid from a Firefox session.
However, if I try to programmatically get a value for sid, by first running something like the following code, then I get no content back when I then run the above code using the value for sid found by the code below:

```
import urllib2, re
url='http://eu.12bet.co.uk/EuroSite/Euro_index.aspx'
http_req_data = None
http_req_header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT' : '1',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive'}
web_req = urllib2.Request(url, http_req_data, http_req_header)  # create request object
web_resp = urllib2.urlopen(web_req)  # open the request object and return a handle
print '==== HEADERS ===='
print web_resp.info()
headers = dict(web_resp.info())
cookies = headers['set-cookie']
print '==== MISC ===='
print "cookies>"+cookies+"<"
sid = re.search('ASP.NET_SessionId=(\w+)',cookies).group(1)
print "sid>"+sid+"<"
```

i have been working on this for ages, and I can't work it out.  It's doing my head in.  Can anyone please clue me in on what is wrong here?  Many thanx in advance.

Comment: Try passing all of the cookies, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There was another cookie value in the first response that is different each time and needs to be caught and sent back with each future request to preserve state/consistency.

Comment: Yeah. They are using incremental updates based on a cookie so their back-end only returns data that has updated as opposed to loading odds for all on-screen markets.